# OpenLayers - ol.Feature(s) Display Properly on Initial Page Load, But Not When Adding New ol.Feature(s) After Page Load Has Completed

Tags: javascript, openlayers-6

I'm in my early OpenLayers learning cycle, and am feeling a bit lost. Everything works fine when I load the page; that is, I have a number of `ol.Feature` objects that get created (sourced from a JSON file) and rendered properly on the map.

The problem I am having occurs when I try to add additional `ol.Feature` objects to the map. By all accounts, everything appears correct internally - the `ol.Feature` object just does not appear on the map.

The following is the BASE JS code used to create the Map:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([mousePositionControl]),
  interactions: defaultInteractions().extend([new Drag()]),
  layers: [ baseMapLayer],
  view: new ol.View({
          center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-70.681715, 19.779147]), 
          zoom: 16 //Initial Zoom Level
        })
});

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: [marker, marker_2]
});
var markerVectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource
});

map.addLayer(markerVectorLayer);
```

The following is the block of code used to create a single `ol.Feature` object:

```
function addMapMarker(sMid, sDid, sLong, sLat)
{
    var marker = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([sLong, sLat]))
        //geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([sLong, sLat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'))
    });

    marker.setId(sDid);

    marker.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon(({
            crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
            src: 'img/ent_mkr/' + sMid
        }))
    }));

    return marker;
}
```

During the initial page load, each `ol.Feature` object as added to an ARRAY object called 'aFeatures':

`var aFeatures  = [];`

This code runs inside a 'forEach' loop, as it extracts data from the JSON file:

`aFeatures.push(addMapMarker(sMarkerId, oEntitiesData.did, oEntitiesData.lon, oEntitiesData.lat));`

Once the 'forEach' loop has completed, the 'aFeatures' array is added into the 'features' property in the `ol.source.Vector` object:

`vectorSource.addFeatures(aFeatures);`

**SO FAR SO GOOD** - the problem occurs when I try to add additional `ol.Feature` object(s) to the `ol.Map` (added one by one). I am basically following the same routine as described above, using the call to the addMapMarker function to create a new `ol.Feature` object:

`var oMapMkr = addMapMarker(sMid, oEntitiesData.did, oEntitiesData.lon, oEntitiesData.lat);`

And then add it into the 'features' property in the `ol.source.Vector` object:

`vectorSource.addFeature(oMapMkr);`

**THE PROBLEM IS:** that after all that, the `ol.Feature` object does not appear on the page. Calling the `render()` or `renderSync()` functions on the `ol.Map` object do not help.

FINALLY - I know the additional post page load `ol.Feature` object(s) are added to the markerVectorLayer, because I stepped through it:

`markerVectorLayer.getSource().getFeatures().forEach(function(item, index)`

I suspect I am missing something very obvious, but I just do not know what that is - LOL Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?  My attempt to do so: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/gvbyxh89/2/) seems to work as expected.

Comment: Thank you for reply @geocodezip . As it turns out, the code I created was fine, and my problem was very basic, having nothing to do with what I posted. The PNG image I was trying to use as the `ol.style.Icon` was corrupted, so nothing actually downloaded to the page. I only discovered that after checking the Network display in the Firefox debugger. 

Please accept my apology for any inconvenience I might have caused you - your interest in helping is very much appreciated.

To others who might read this post - the code I present above is good.

Comment: That is what makes creating a [mcve] valuable

Answer (score 0):

As it so happens folks, I was 100% correct when I ended my initial question with:

*I suspect I am missing something very obvious, but I just do not know what that is - LOL*

The code I created was fine, and my problem was indeed very basic, having nothing to do with what I posted. The PNG image I was trying to use as the `ol.style.Icon` was corrupted, so nothing actually downloaded to the page. I only discovered that after checking the Network display in the Firefox debugger.

This issue can be considered closed - thank you!